# Remove a single struct field from byte slice

Tags: go, struct, byte, slice

I'm wondering how to modify the bytes in my Write method.

The bytes to remove make up a stack trace of a type from a logging service, which is part of a `type errWithStackTrace struct` so I can get that value by using json.Unmarshal on the byte slice as seen below. If that stack trace is present I'd like everything written except it.

```
    func (w *customWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
        e := loggedEvent{}
        if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &e); err != nil {
            return len(p), nil
        }
        if e.ErrWithStack.Stacktrace != nil {
            // modify p to remove e.ErrWithStack.Stacktrace bytes?
            return os.Stdout(p)
        }
        return os.Stdout(p)
    }
```

I tried converting `e.ErrWithStack.Stacktrace` to bytes and then replacing it but it still writes the entire event.

```
    if e.ErrWithStack.Stacktrace != nil {
        reqBytes := new(bytes.Buffer)
        json.NewEncoder(reqBytes).Encode(e.ErrWithStack.Stacktrace)
        res := bytes.Replace(p, reqBytes.Bytes(), []byte(""), 1)
        return os.Stdout.Write(res)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return os.Stdout(p)` doesn't make sense here, but in any case, the ultimate problem is that if the input is json, and you have decoded it, you don't know what the original input is.  There's no easy way to *find* the string to remove, as what *you* have is already decoded.

You could of course write your own json parser and find and remove the item that way.  That's the only way to preserve the *rest* of the encoding as is.

A simpler option is to remove the error and re-encode.  There is enough that you have not shown here that it is hard to know whether this would be OK, but I took your sample routine, made it compile-able, and built a small test framework for it, but here it is (and [a link to the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kwbd1ImujW2)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type loggedEvent struct {
    Thing1            string  `json:"thing1"`
    ErrWithStackTrace *string `json:"err,omitempty"`
    Thing2            string  `json:"thing2"`
}

var inputs [][]byte = [][]byte{
    []byte(`{"thing1":"a string","err":"here is a stack trace","thing2":"another string"}`),
    []byte(`{"thing1":"a\u0020string","err":"here\u0020is\u0020a\u0020stack\u0020trace","thing2":"u-encoded"}`),
    []byte(`{"thing1":"more strings","thing2":"no error this time"}`),
}

type customWriter struct{}

func (w *customWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    e := loggedEvent{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &e); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("note: unable to unmarshal %q\n", p)
        return len(p), nil
    }
    if e.ErrWithStackTrace != nil {
        // fmt.Printf("note: removing ErrWithStackTrace part\n")
        e.ErrWithStackTrace = nil
    }
    s, err := json.Marshal(e)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("help, failed to re-marshal e=%v: err=%v\n", e, err)
        return 0, err
    }
    s = append(s, '\n')
    return os.Stdout.Write(s)
}

func main() {
    w := &customWriter{}
    for _, inp := range inputs {
        ret, err := w.Write(inp)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("ret = %d, err = %v\n", ret, err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered re-encoding but thought perhaps there was a simpler way. The major difference still challenging me is that `loggedEvent` instead has a field, `Field map[string]interface{} `json:"-"`` to accept unknown JSON data types  (like here https://socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-decode-unmarshal-unknown-json-data-type-with-map-string-interface) and those aren't being captured in the write now.

Do you know if you have to range through the fields and create some type of new object to pass to `json.Marshal` ? Your solution is very close though and helpful!

Comment: You can marshal from a map[string]interface{}, if you like. Consider doing the unmarshal into *just* a `map[string]interface{}` or `interface{}`, so that *all* fields are handled the same way. Then check the result to see if it has an unwanted field to delete, which is now easy enough (it's in a `map[string]interface{}`) and re-marshal if necessary.